# Print Current Module Name in Swift

Tags: swift

How can I print the module name for a class in swift?

`self.dynamicType` prints only the class name without the module. How can I print the module?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Swift's introspection support is not very good right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot jtbandes! The answer below is what I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the not-so-pretty but currently working way, try:

```
let object = NSStringFromClass(MyClass) as NSString
let module = object.componentsSeparatedByString(".").first!
```

This doesn't seem to work for Foundation/UIKit etc objects though

Comment: Yes, my question were exactly for Swift classes. I think your trick works for my situation. Thank you.

Comment: NSStringFromClass(ConfigurationManager.self).componentsSeparatedByString(".")[0]
We don't need to cast it to NSString.

Comment: @mohamede1945 ah cool - probably was confused because we have to cast for methods like `lastPathComponent`

Comment: Updated for swift 4: `let module = NSStringFromClass(MyClass).components(separatedBy:".")[0]`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a different solution

```
// "To parse a #fileID expression, read the module name as the text before the first slash (/) and the filename as the text after the last slash"
func moduleName(fileId: String = #fileID) -> String? {
   fileId.firstIndex(of: "/").flatMap { String(fileId[fileId.startIndex ..< $0]) }
}
```

Comment: That would be `#fileID` (note the capital `ID`). Also, why don't you just split on `/` and get the first component?

Comment: @Alladinian that's more expensive since it needs to process the entire string, using range stops the logic as soon as it reaches the first `/`

Comment: Expensive? How long can be the string? I get your point but imo this is a case where readability is more important than performance...

Answer (score 0):

And yet another way to print the current module name... in `Swift`.

```swift
let module = String(String(reflecting: MY_SUBJECT.self).prefix { $0 != "." })
```

Comment: i would discourage to use reflecting as it is described "Use this initializer to convert an instance of any type to its custom debugging representation"

Comment: @PeterLapisu I appreciate the clarification. Indeed, this explanation is indicated in the Apple documentation, but for a number of reasons it is incomplete. But by the way, if you can't offer your solution, then it's mostly useless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that doesn't use `NSString`/Obj-C code, and is instead pure-Swift (thus, faster and cross-platform):

```
let moduleName = String(reflecting: Self.self)
    .split(separator: ".", maxSplits: 1).first ?? ""
```

Comment: i would discourage to use reflecting as it is described "Use this initializer to convert an instance of any type to its custom debugging representation"

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a module name from `#fileID` macro which contains an unique identifier in the form `module/file` by the following simple code:

```swift
let moduleName = NSString(#fileID).pathComponents.first!
```