# How to solve the issue "Cannot assign value of type '[Сategory]' to type '[Category]' (aka 'Array<OpaquePointer>')"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
protocol GenericApi {
    var session: URLSession { get }
    var decoder: JSONDecoder { get }
    func fetch<T: Codable>(type: T.Type, from urlString: String) async throws -> T }
}

extension GenericApi {
    func fetch<T: Codable>(type: T.Type, from urlString: String) async throws -> T {
    
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { throw URLError(.badURL) }
    
        let (data, response) = try await session.data(from: url)
    
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw URLError(.badServerResponse) }
            
        if 200..<300 ~= response.statusCode {
            do {
                return try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        fatalError("HTTP status code: \(response.statusCode)")
    } 
}
```

This is my protocol.

I've created the protocol with generic func and opaque type, and then when I've implemented that code I got the error:

> "Cannot assign value of type '[Сategory]' to type '[Category]'
> (aka 'Array<OpaquePointer>')"

How can I assign one result to another?

```
 // MARK: - Categories 
 struct Categories: Codable {
    let results: [Сategory] 
 }

// MARK: - Сategory 
 struct Сategory: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let imageURL: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case imageURL = "image_url"
    }
}
```

My model.

```
 @Published private(set) var categories: [Category] = []
 func fetchCategories() async {
    do {
        let response = try await networkManager.fetch(type: Categories.self,
                                       from: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/058729bd-1402-4578-88de-265481fd7d54")
            categories = response.results

    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
 }
```

And the function where I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a name conflict. The word `Category` in this line:

```
@Published private(set) var categories: [Category] = []
```

actually refers to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/category) `Category`.

```
typealias Category = OpaquePointer
```

This is a type representing Objective-C *categories* (which is something similar to extensions in Swift). Clearly, that is not what you mean.

This `Category` typealias is being preferred over the one you declared.

You can stop this from happening by adding your module name as a prefix. Your module name is typically the same as your Xcode target's name.

```
@Published private(set) var categories: [YourApp.Category] = []
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32660443/5133585) if you are confused about what your module name is.

Or, you can just rename your `Category` to something else.

Comment: thanks a lot bro, i appreciate it, it took a while trying to solve it